# Rails - React is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, undefined, react-rails

First of all, this is not a duplicate! It's the same 'not defined' error but follows exactly the github (https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) guide and still not working

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'react-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
```

application.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>project</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'react' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
```

components/app.js.jsx:

```
// var React = window.ReactRailsUJS;

var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p>Hello</p>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello />,
    document.getElementById("react-msg")
);

console.log(1);
```

html file:

```
<style type="text/css">
  h1, h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <h1>React JS</h1>
  <h3 id="react-msg"></h3>
</div>
```

development.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
...

# config/environments/development.rb
config.react.variant = :development

# to include react add-ons
config.react.addons = true # defaults to false

end
```

When I visit the page it says

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

What I did wrong?

If I uncomment the following

```
var React = window.ReactRailsUJS;
```

it says createClass is not a function and same for every other React function

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, still not working. I tried the same thing on Cloud9 on other project so it's not a "project bug" either

Comment: guessing your browser had not been aware of react at the time you had called it

Comment: Did you include your `application.js` in layout?

Comment: I did. I modified the question with application.html content

Comment: No one knows the damn answer?

Comment: @Drew is right. javascript_include_tag 'application' should come after the javascript_include_tag 'react' line

Comment: Have u tried `//= require_tree components` ?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that runs onto this issue and lands here, apparently it is a problem beginning with version 16 onward of React. The reason is cause `React.createClass` is deprecated. Instead, you're supposed to use `createReactClass`.

Much of the (now old) documentation provided an example like this:

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>
    )
  }
});
```

Instead, you should use this:

```
var HelloMessage = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>
    )
  }
});
```

I can only assume they didn't update their examples, and many of them are still showing up when you search for `react-rails` as of Nov-2017.